# Is there an open source java enum of ISO 3166-1 country codes

Tags: java, internationalization, country-codes, iso-3166

Does anyone know of a freely available java 1.5 package that provides a list of ISO 3166-1 country codes as a enum or EnumMap?  Specifically I need the "ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 code elements", i.e. the 2 character country code like "us", "uk", "de", etc.  Creating one is simple enough (although tedious), but if there's a standard one already out there in apache land or the like it would save a little time.

Comment: Note that ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 for Great Britain is GB not UK as in your question.

Comment: @Ken yes you can but then you have to maintain that list and keep it in sync with wikipedia. The problem grows...

Answer (score 126):

Now an implementation of country code ([ISO 3166-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1) [alpha-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)/[alpha-3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3)/[numeric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric)) list as Java enum is available at GitHub under Apache License version 2.0.

**Example:**

```java
CountryCode cc = CountryCode.getByCode("JP");

System.out.println("Country name = " + cc.getName());                // "Japan"
System.out.println("ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code = " + cc.getAlpha2());   // "JP"
System.out.println("ISO 3166-1 alpha-3 code = " + cc.getAlpha3());   // "JPN"
System.out.println("ISO 3166-1 numeric code = " + cc.getNumeric());  // 392
```

---

**Last Edit** 2016-Jun-09

CountryCode enum was packaged into com.neovisionaries.i18n with other Java enums, LanguageCode ([ISO 639-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1)), LanguageAlpha3Code ([ISO 639-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2)), LocaleCode, ScriptCode ([ISO 15924](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_15924)) and CurrencyCode ([ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217)) and registered into the Maven Central Repository.

**Maven**

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.neovisionaries</groupId>
  <artifactId>nv-i18n</artifactId>
  <version>1.29</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.29'
}
```

**GitHub**

https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-i18n

**Javadoc**

https://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-i18n/

**OSGi**

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.neovisionaries.i18n
Export-Package: com.neovisionaries.i18n;version="1.28.0"
```

Comment: Hi Takahiko thanks for that! I just added three missing countries, sorry I was in a hurry and I just forked the repo, you'll find the updates here:
https://github.com/bbossola/CountryCode

Comment: Hi Bruno! Thank you for finding the missing entries (AL, AN and GN). I referred to your forked repository and manually copied them to my repository. Thank you!

Comment: In case you are doing banking stuff, there is an Apache-2-licensed library called "[iban4j](https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/iban4j/)" (namespace `org.iban4j`) to handle IBAN and BIC codes and it also has a CountryCode enum: [CountryCode](https://github.com/arturmkrtchyan/iban4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/iban4j/CountryCode.java)

Answer (score 60):

This code gets 242 countries in Sun Java 6:

```
String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
```

Though [the ISO website](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm) claims there are 249 *ISO 3166-1-alpha-2 code elements*, though the [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) links to the same information.

Comment: This information is hardcoded. You would need to update JRE regulary to keep updated :)

Comment: In Java 7 there are 247 countries, still less than in the official standard (which is 249).

Comment: The ones missing are: SOUTH SUDAN (SS) and SINT MAARTEN (DUTCH PART) (SX)

Comment: `Java 1.6.0_33-b05` includes 248, only missing out `SS` now. This is simply because `SS` is the most recent (2011) country to be added and Java 6 source has not been updated.

Comment: The OP is asking for "a freely available java 1.5 package": how an answer requesting Java6 or Java7 applies to that? Downvoted.

Comment: On java version: **1.8.0_152** there are 250 country codes available

Comment: Note that if you are planning on using the display names of this library, they are not all up to ISO3166 standard: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8245072

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I generated an enum with country code + country name:

```
package countryenum;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class CountryEnumGenerator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();
        List<Country> list = new ArrayList<Country>(countryCodes.length);

        for (String cc : countryCodes) {
            list.add(new Country(cc.toUpperCase(), new Locale("", cc).getDisplayCountry()));
        }

        Collections.sort(list);

        for (Country c : list) {
            System.out.println("/**" + c.getName() + "*/");
            System.out.println(c.getCode() + "(\"" + c.getName() + "\"),");
        }

    }
}

class Country implements Comparable<Country> {
    private String code;
    private String name;

    public Country(String code, String name) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }


    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Country o) {
        return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: added one line in print to enable intellitxt

Comment: @David it generates the body of an enum

Comment: Nice generation code, but you need to remove the special characters. For example CÔTE_D'IVOIRE cannot be used as an enum :P.

Comment: Note that the names of this library are not up to ISO3166 standard: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8245072

Answer (score 11):

If you are already going to rely on Java locale, then I suggest using a simple HashMap instead of creating new classes for countries etc.

Here's how I would use it if I were to rely on the Java Localization only:

```
private HashMap<String, String> countries = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] countryCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

for (String cc : countryCodes) {
    // country name , country code map
    countries.put(new Locale("", cc).getDisplayCountry(), cc.toUpperCase());
}
```

After you fill the map, you can get the ISO code from the country name whenever you need it.
Or you can make it a ISO code to Country name map as well, just modify the 'put' method accordingly.

Comment: Note that the display countries are not all up to the ISO3166 standard: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8245072

Answer (score 3):

There is an easy way to generate this enum with the language name.
Execute this code to generate the list of enum fields to paste :

```
 /**
  * This is the code used to generate the enum content
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String[] codes = java.util.Locale.getISOLanguages();
  for (String isoCode: codes) {
   Locale locale = new Locale(isoCode);
   System.out.println(isoCode.toUpperCase() + "(\"" + locale.getDisplayLanguage(locale) + "\"),");
  }
 }
```

Comment: This gives you a list of languages, not countries.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone is already using the Amazon AWS SDK it includes `com.amazonaws.services.route53domains.model.CountryCode`. I know this is not ideal but it's an alternative if you already use the AWS SDK. For most cases I would use Takahiko's `nv-i18n` since, as he mentions, it implements ISO 3166-1.

Answer (score 2):

AWS Java SDK has [CountryCode](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/route53domains/model/CountryCode.html).

Answer (score 1):

Not a java enum, but a JSON version of this is available at http://country.io/names.json

Answer (score 1):

There is standard [`java.util.Locale.IsoCountryCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.IsoCountryCode.html) since Java 9.

It uses the data from [java/util/LocaleISOData.java](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LocaleISOData.java).

Comment: Does it include countries like `US` and `DE`?

Comment: @darw , yes: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/LocaleISOData.java.

Answer (score 0):

This still does not answer the question. I was also looking for a kind of enumerator for this, and did not find anything. Some examples using hashtable here, but represent the same as the built-in get

I would go for a different approach. So I created a script in python to automatically generate the list in Java:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
f = open("data.txt", 'r')
data = []
cc = {}

for l in f:
    t = l.split('\t')
    cc = { 'code': str(t[0]).strip(), 
           'name': str(t[1]).strip()
    }
    data.append(cc)
f.close()

for c in data:
    print """
/**
 * Defines the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2">ISO_3166-1_alpha-2</a> 
 * for <b><i>%(name)s</i></b>.
 * <p>
 * This constant holds the value of <b>{@value}</b>.
 *
 * @since 1.0
 *
 */
 public static final String %(code)s = \"%(code)s\";""" % c
```

where the data.txt file is a simple copy&paste from Wikipedia table (just remove all extra lines, making sure you have a country code and country name per line).

Then just place this into your static class:

```
/**
 * Holds <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2">ISO_3166-1_alpha-2</a>
 * constant values for all countries. 
 * 
 * @since 1.0
 * 
 * </p>
 */
public class CountryCode {

    /**
     * Constructor defined as <code>private</code> purposefully to ensure this 
     * class is only used to access its static properties and/or methods.  
     */
    private CountryCode() { }

    /**
     * Defines the <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2">ISO_3166-1_alpha-2</a> 
     * for <b><i>Andorra</i></b>.
     * <p>
     * This constant holds the value of <b>{@value}</b>.
     *
     * @since 1.0
     *
     */
     public static final String AD = "AD";

         //
         // and the list goes on! ...
         //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about this question till I had just recently open-sourced my Java enum for exactly this purpose! Amazing coincidence!

I put the whole source code on my blog with BSD caluse 3 license so I don't think anyone would have any beefs about it.

Can be found here.
https://subversivebytes.wordpress.com/2013/10/07/java-iso-3166-java-enum/

Hope it is useful and eases development pains.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an enum, which you address by the english country name. See [country-util](https://github.com/Hervian/country-util).
On each enum you can call `getLocale()` to get the Java Locale.

From the Locale you can get all the information you are used to, fx the ISO-3166-1 two letter country code.

```java
public enum Country{

    ANDORRA(new Locale("AD")),
    AFGHANISTAN(new Locale("AF")),
    ANTIGUA_AND_BARBUDA(new Locale("AG")),
    ANGUILLA(new Locale("AI")),
    //etc
    ZAMBIA(new Locale("ZM")),
    ZIMBABWE(new Locale("ZW"));

    private Locale locale;

    private Country(Locale locale){
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public Locale getLocale(){
        return locale;
    }
```

Pro:

- Light weight
- Maps to Java Locales
- Addressable by full country name
- Enum values are not hardcoded, but generated by a call to Locale.getISOCountries(). That is: Simply recompile the project against the newest java version to get any changes made to the list of countries reflected in the enum.

Con:

- Not in Maven repository
- Most likely simpler / less expressive than the other solutions, which I don't know.
- Created for my own needs / not as such maintained. - You should probably clone the repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found the IsoCountry list [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LocaleISOData.java#l226), it has 2 and 3 char country codes

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the current device locale in Alpha-3 ISO (XXX) format:

```
fun getCurrentCountryCode(): String? {
    val tm = context.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val countryCodeValue = tm.networkCountryIso

    val locale: Locale? = Locale.getAvailableLocales().firstOrNull {
        it.country.lowercase() == countryCodeValue.lowercase()
    }

    return locale?.isO3Country
}
```

To obtain the current device language locale (xx-XX) format:

```
fun getCurrentLocale(): String? {
    return try {
        val locale = context.resources.configuration.locales[0]
        return "${locale.language}-${locale.country}"
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[JCountry](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/io.github.castmart/jcountry/0.0.2/overview) is an open source library containing the ISO 3166-1 codes, and it's corresponding country name translations to different languages. It is a wrapper for the debian iso-codes info. It also contains the iso codes for languages (iso 639-2) and the corresponding language name translations.

```
// Maven
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.castmart</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcountry</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the repo: https://github.com/castmart/jcountry

```
JCountry jcountry = JCountry.getInstance();
CountryDB countryDB = jcountry.getCountriesDB();
// Get the countries DB hash maps <String, Country>
HashMap<String, Country> dbByAlpha2 = countryDB.getCountriesMapByAlpha2();
HashMap<String, Country> dbByAlpha3 = countryDB.getCountriesMapByAlpha3();
HashMap<String, Country> dbByName = countryDB.getCountriesMapByName();

// Get Translations by language based locale 
Optional<ResourceBundle> bundle = countryDB.getCountriesTranslations(Locale.GERMAN);

// MX -> Mexiko
String translatedCountryName = bundle.get().getString(dbByAlpha2.get("MX").getName());

// Languages DB
LanguageDB languageDB = new LanguageDBImpl(true);
HashMap<String, Language> dbByAlpha2 = languageDB.getLanguagesMapByAlpha2();

// Get Translations by language based locale 
Optional<ResourceBundle> bundle = languageDB.getLanguagesTranslations(Locale.GERMAN);

// Spanisch (Kastilisch)
String translatedCountryName = bundle.get().getString(dbByAlpha2.get("es").getName());
```

Comment: What type do `var`s resolve to? It's not very obvious from the context. Especially, for people reading this who don't already know the library

Comment: Good point, I already updated it