# how can i get Country name from ISO3166-1 alpha-2 country code in java

Tags: java-8, appserver

I am getting **ISO alpha-2 country code** from the server in the response of an API but I need to convert that **ISO alpha-2 country code** to the country name. I am using Java 8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an open source java enum of ISO 3166-1 country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139867/is-there-an-open-source-java-enum-of-iso-3166-1-country-codes)

Answer (score 1):

Using the below code, we can get all the countries ISO3 code and ISO2 code, and country names from Java 8 locale.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {   
  String[] isoCountries = Locale.getISOCountries();
    for (String country : isoCountries) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en", country);
        String iso = locale.getISO3Country();
        String code = locale.getCountry();
        String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        System.out.println(iso + " " + code + " " + name);
    }
}
```

You can also create a lookup table map to convert in between ISO codes. As I need to convert between iso3 to iso2 so create the map according.

```
String[] isoCountries = Locale.getISOCountries();
    Map<String, String> countriesMapping = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String country : isoCountries) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("en", country);
        String iso = locale.getISO3Country();
        String code = locale.getCountry();
        String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();
        countriesMapping.put(iso, code);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the answers for this question: [Is there an open source java enum of ISO 3166-1 country codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139867/is-there-an-open-source-java-enum-of-iso-3166-1-country-codes)

You should be able to add a library to your application to let you get the name of a country via the code.

Comment: I was trying to avoid open-source or 3rd party library and I found a way to convert ISO alpha-2 country code to the country name using java 8 build-in locale.